# Daily notification of bad traffic along commute home

Tags: applications, notifications

Is there an app that will notify me at a time i specify for days i specify (or weekdays) if there is currently heavy traffic on the route from my current location to a location i specify?
Ideally with the option of then viewing the route on a map.

Note: I'm in the UK, although i'm hoping for a solution that works with google maps traffic data, so fingers crossed for an app that works where google maps traffic works.

---

I know there are widgets that show route traffic status, but i'd like to avoid having to check my phone, instead relying on the (absence of a) notification.

Answer (score 1):

Not specific to Android, but [traffic.com](http://www.traffic.com) lets you define "drives" and will send SMS and/or email alerts if issues are detected. Other sites have similar features.

Comment: Thanks. If a can find a uk equivalent then I might have do in with something like this. Deleting the emails could get annoying, and it wouldn't be as integrated as I'd hoped

Comment: Ah. You didn't mention country. Have you searched in the market for "[traffic](https://market.android.com/search?q=traffic+uk)"?

Comment: http://www.keepmoving.co.uk/

Comment: Thanks, i had searched and could only find ones to view traffic, not get notified about it, websites i've found don't offer the control i want either.